# Stop taking input in text-field (tag input)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am taking some tags name like "study","reading" something like that in the textfield with the help of [Bootstrap 4 Tag Input Plugin With jQuery - Tagsinput.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-4-Tag-Input-Plugin-jQuery.html) and I have also some predefine tags name contain by buttons. If I click the button then the count of the tag's will increase (count++) and again click this button count will decrease(count--). Same rules for the text-field tags and the total count of the tags in both fields (text and buttons)<=5.

I can count the total tags of the both field but can't stop taking input in text-field when it is greater than 5.

html

```
<button class="btnr btnr-tags-optional" id="1" onclick="tagSelect(this.id)" >1</button>
<button class="btnr btnr-tags-optional" id="2" onclick="tagSelect(this.id)" >2</button>
<button class="btnr btnr-tags-optional" id="3" onclick="tagSelect(this.id)" >3</button>
```

My Js

```
var tagsCount = 0;
var store = 0;
var total_tags = 0;

function tagSelect(clicked_id) {
    if (total_tags < 5) {
        var tags = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
        if (tags.style.borderColor == "rgb(255, 72, 20)") {
            tags.style.borderColor = "";
            tagsCount--;
        } else if (tags.style.borderColor == "") {
            tags.style.borderColor = 'rgb(255, 72, 20)';
            tagsCount++;
        }
        total_tags = store + tagsCount;
    }
    console.log(total_tags);
}
$('#tags_text').on('change', function() {

    if (total_tags >= 5) {
        $("#tags_text").attr('readonly');
        console.log('condition')
    } else {
        $("#tags_text").removeAttr('readonly');
        var items = $("#tags_text").tagsinput('items').length;
        store = items;
        total_tags = store + tagsCount;
        console.log(total_tags);
    }


});
```

[Here is the example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25ctqu7j/3/)

Comment: Are you sure you provided the correct `fiddle` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save this fiddle. Now I have updated this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved.
I have changed the maxTags value of the plugin with the change of the tags click.

```
window.tagsCount = 0;
var store = 0;
var total_tags = 0;

function tagSelect(clicked_id) {

    var r = ("#" + clicked_id).toString();
 
    if (total_tags < 5) {

        
        if ($(r).hasClass("classActiveIssue")) {

            $(r).removeClass("classActiveIssue");
            window.tagsCount--;
           
        } else {
            $(r).addClass("classActiveIssue");
            window.tagsCount++;
           
        }


    } else {
       
        if ($(r).hasClass("classActiveIssue")) {
            $(r).removeClass("classActiveIssue");
            window.tagsCount--;
        }
    }
    total_tags = store + tagsCount;
    $("#optionsleft").text(total_tags + "/5 selected");
    //console.log("total",total_tags);
}
$('#tags_text').on('change', function() {


    var items = $("#tags_text").tagsinput('items').length;
    store = items;
    total_tags = store + tagsCount;
 

});
```

and add the line in add:

```
self.options.maxTags = 5 - window.tagsCount;
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u91475gf/)